# NodeJs + Unable to access localStorage inside routes.js

Tags: node.js, express

In my NODEjs ( using Express ) application, I want to use Country Code inside routes.js but I am unable to access localstorage inside the routes.js

Please provide some solution.

Answer (score 1):

`LocalStorage` is only available in browsers on the `Window` object.

The `Window` object is not available server side.

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Following your comment, you could implement a route in your express application which takes the IP as part of the body.
For this to work you will need [`body-parser`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser) middleware. Example application:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var server;

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/api/ip', function (req, res) {
  res.send(req.body.ip);
});

server = app.listen(3000);
```

This would return the posted IP.

Comment: Thanks. Any other way to send country code to NodeJs routes.

Comment: You would need to post it to the server. So in express you could have a route that takes the country code as part of the request body, and then does what you want based on that

Comment: Any reference you can share if possible. I am new to express js

Comment: Can I use Global variable for this ?

Comment: No, the client and server are separate. The only way to pass information between them is through an API. Luckily, APIs are super easy to create in express. I have added an example to my answer

Comment: @Rubyist i have updated the example to be more thorough and update some deprecated syntax